# How to use Azure Data Factory IF Activity?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

[image]

I am getting value cnt=1 from my query in LookUp Activity.

Now I want to check if cnt value is 1 in IF activity then run another activity.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution.

Below is the working code for my problem:

```
@equals(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.cnt,1)
```